# Access a vector element with a string

Tags: rust

In the rust book we have the following code

```
#[test]
    fn one_result() {
        let query = "duct";
        let contents = "\
Rust:
safe, fast, productive.
Pick three.";

        assert_eq!(vec!["safe, fast, productive."], search(query, contents));
    }
```

and the function for searching is:

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }

    results
}
```

How does `assert_eq` access the vector element with a string? I cannot find any description about such functionality

Comment: Are you referring to `vec!["safe, fast, productive."]`?

Comment: Yes, it seems that it just creates a single element vector, I got it completely wrong the first time I saw it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_eq!` does not access vector elements by string. It compares equality (==) of the two vectors.

`assert_eq!` is also just syntactic sugar for checking equality, otherwise panicking.
In other words, this is the same as your assert:

```
if vec!["safe, fast, productive."] != search(query, contents) {
    panic!()
}
```

Keep reading the book to find out about Traits, notably the `Eq` and `PartialEq` traits, which are responsible for testing equality in rust.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. The code

`assert_eq!(vec!["safe, fast, productive."], search(query, contents));`

creates a vector with elements of type `String` with only one entry that contains the text “safe, fast, productive.” and then compares this vector with the returned vector from the search function. So it does not try to access vector elements with strings, but compares vectors that contain only one element each